# Middleware to redirect to other API endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have built an API for users to login to my application and to retrieve a JWT token (plush refresh one). This is done using an unprotected route. The same API has also some other routes, always related to user profile, that are protected by a middleware that check if the Access or the Refresh token are valid and in case gives you access to the route. So fa so good this is done with this code:

```
// Route to fetch user profile info
router.post('/countmyitems', verifyToken, countMyIssues);
```

but we are inside one specific API.
Now assume that I want to create a separate API for other things to manage in my application (I want to have separate endpoints for different functionalities). I see two alternatives:

- I clone this API, remove the unprotected routes and change the protected routes to match the new functionalities;
- I create a new API for the new functionalities and I use this user API middleware to protect it.

In the first scenario, each time I do some changes on the authorization part I have to replicate it for each API (if I change the middleware).

In the second scenario I change this to something like (pseudocode):

```
// Route to fetch other info
router.post('/otherendpoint', verifyToken, http://localhost:4001/api/otherendpoint);
```

where localhost:4001 is the server for the new API

Is alternative two manageable? How can I set it up?

Comment: @isherwood what is not clear on my question? I am looking for a way to protect different endpoints with JWT validation keeping the code to validate the JWT on one endpoint only.

Comment: You'll notice that I mentioned your _title_, which is vague and not a question. Again, see [ask] for tips and examples of good titles. We shouldn't all have to wander in here to see what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You could create a **common node module package for all your verification functions**.

1. Create a new package (f.ex. package-verification-lelio) with all common verification code.

   `npm init`
2. Create some functions. F.ex. in your index.js:

   ```
   function jwtVerification() {
       return true
   }

   module.exports.jwtVerification = jwtVerification;
   ```
3. Create a link to this package to be reused in every resource api.

   `npm link`
4. In every resource api. Link to this verification package. This will add your verification package in the node_modules of your resource api.

   `npm link package-verification-lelio`
5. Use the verification functions (as middleware in your case) by including them in your resource api.

   ```
   const jwtVerification = require('package-verification-lelio')
   console.log(jwtVerification()) // Returns true
   ```

Now you will only have one package with all verification code. Every time you update this verification package, every resource api will use the latest version.

NB: I wouldn't put any authentication functions in this package since those should be in a separate api accessible by the client.

Comment: actually this is my first option... the point is that this way I duplicate the code for the validation and I don't want to have to mantain it in several locations